# Android WebView overview mode loads image zoomed in

Tags: android, image, webview, scale

I'm using following code to display an image in a WebView:

```
    final WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    web.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(false);
    web.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
    web.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
    web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    String url = extras.getString("url");
    String x = "<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\"/><style type=\"text/css\">html, body {margin: 0;padding: 0;} img {border: none;}</style><head><body style=\"background: black;\"><table><tr><td align=\"center\"><img src=\"" + url + "\" /></td></tr></table></body></html>";
    web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, x, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

According to the manual, it should be started in overview mode, so it should be maximally zoomed out (and that's what I want to do). Unfortunately, the image is zoomed in. How can I fix it?

Comment: It would help if you link to the manual that says this ought to work...

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening here is that the `width=device-width` says the viewport should be 480 pixels wide (or whatever the device is).  So an image that's wider than that will be partly off the screen and need to be scrolled.

If you want the page to open in overview mode, I think you should set that when creating the WebView and not specify any `viewport`.